# cv2.fillPoly strange results

Tags: python, opencv

Trying to rasterize simple poly using `cv2.fillPoly` I get strange result - sum of no zero pixels is 10201, but it should be 100*100.

```
pts = np.array([[0, 0], [100, 0], [100, 100], [0, 100], [0, 0]])
img = np.zeros((256, 256))
vertices = np.array([pts], dtype=np.int32)
mask = cv2.fillPoly(img, vertices, color=255)
print('np.count_nonzero(mask)', np.count_nonzero(mask))
```

What wrong?

Comment: Off-by one error -- it should be `101 * 101` (which it is), since you have an edge in column 100 and row 100. Imagine in small scale  (`[[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0]]`) that's 4 lines, covering 4 pixels (and nothing to fill).

Comment: @DanMašek Oh, yes.

Comment: I made some pixelart to illustrate it for others, but I totally understand if you delete the question too ;) (it happens)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a simple off-by-one error -- it should be `101 * 101` (which is 10201).

To illustrate why, let's scale the problem down, and run your algorithm of the following set of points:

```
[[0, 0], [2, 0], [2, 2], [0, 2], [0, 0]]
```

and illustrate the progress on the following grid:

[image]

The call to `cv2.fillPoly` with those vertices does (conceptually) the following 5 things:

- Draw line from `(0,0)` to `(2,0)`

  [image]
- Draw line from `(2,0)`, to `(2,2)`

  [image]
- Draw line from `(2,2)`, to `(0,2)`

  [image]
- Draw line from `(0,2)`, to `(0,0)`

  [image]
- Fill the polygon

  [image]

The result being

[image]

As you can see, there are 9 pixels filled:

- 3 columns are used (0 to 2, inclusive, meaning `(2 - 0) + 1 == 3`).
- 3 rows are used (0 to 2, inclusive, meaning `(2 - 0) + 1 == 3`).

---

Similarly, in your case: `(100 - 0 + 1) * (100 - 0 + 1) = 101 * 101 = 10201`